# Вопрос по сессиям в php

Tags: php, сессия

Допустим на сайте авторизированы несколько пользователей таким образом:

```
session_start();
$SESSION['login'] = $login;
```

Возможно ли каким то образом узнать какие сейчас логины авторизированы запуском скрипа кроном?
На сколько мне известно каждая сессия уникальна и имеет свой ID, возможно можно как то узнать какие сессии живы и какому логину принадлежат?

Answer (score 2):

С помощью session_save_path получаете папку, куда php хранит сессии.
Далее читаете файлы из папки и декодируете с помощью session_decode. Смотрите на наличие в сессии переменной login. И т.д.

Answer (score 0):

да просто пиши в базу данные сессии, если на то пошло

```
mysql_query("UPDATE user SET time='".time()."' WHERE session_id='".$session_id."'",$db); // обновляем время (для проверки кто онлайн)
```

И постоянно просто пусть обновляется, ну и проверяй например онлайн только если time в базе не больше 5 минут от текущего времени.